# Allocation operator overloading

Tags: c++, allocation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;

struct C{ };

struct A
{
    void* operator new(std::size_t, C*, C*){ A a; return &a; }
};

A *a= new A; //candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided


int main(){ }
```

I haven't been understanding this error.

> if the allocated type is a class type T or array thereof, the
>   allocation function’s name is looked up in the scope of T. If this
>   lookup fails to find the name, or if the allocated type is not a class
>   type, the allocation function’s name is looked up in the global scope.

We have implicitly defined allocation function in the global scope, provided by library. What's a problem? I expected that overload resolution will be applied.

I also would like to understand, what is the point of use such allocation function (with three parameters).

Comment: From [new's documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new): `Note, that as per name lookup rules, any allocation functions declared in class scope hides all global allocation functions for the new-expressions that attempt to allocate objects of this class.` Your overload shadows the one that should be used for `new A` (which is probably `new(std::size_t)`)

Comment: @Nobody Very interesting. Is there in N3797 working draft?

Comment: @St.Antario It's in the quote you gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the quote says, it will only look up the allocation function in the global scope **if looking it up in the class's scope fails to find the name**. In your case, it is finding the name, so doesn't look it up in the global scope. The only problem is that your allocation function has the wrong number of arguments for the way you're calling it.

If you want to ensure the global allocation function is used:

```
A *a = ::new A;
```

If you want to call the allocation function you defined, you need to do:

```
A *a = new (someC, someOtherC) A;
```

Comment: Can this allocation function be invoked in anything way at all?

Comment: Of course, instead of explicitly calling class member function operator new(std::size_t, C*, C*). I mean invocation via new-expression.

Comment: @St.Antario Preceding a new expression with `::` forces it to look up the allocation functions in global scope.

Comment: @St.Antario: Did you try actually passing the arguments to new? `new A(ptrToC, ptrToC)`

Comment: @Nobody I want to invoke my explicitly defined function via new-expression/

Comment: @St.Antario Added that to my answer.